# Push array into JSON object

Tags: arrays, json

Im trying to set up a JSON Object with various pieces of basic info in it. I almost have it working, however I'd like to have an item called 'items' and in that have 4 or 5 item arrays. You can see below I loop through the elements I want, but I can't work out how to add them collectively into `products['items']`. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

```
        products = {}
        
        products['message'] = 'this is a test message'
        products['main_id'] = '10301'
        
        $(select_checkbox).each(function(index, value) {
          
            if($(this).prop("checked")) {
                                        
                var item_id = $(this).attr('id')
                var parent = $(this).closest('.bag_item')
                var thumb_url = parent.find('.menu_thumb').css('background-image');
                
                item = {}
                item["item_id"] = item_id;
                item["thumb_url"] = thumb_url;
                
                products['items'].push(item)
                
            }
            
        })

        alert(JSON.stringify(products))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create the `products['items']` first (*set it to an empty array*)

```
products = {}
    
products['message'] = 'this is a test message'
products['main_id'] = '10301'
products['items'] = [];  // added this line to initialize the items prop.
```